# Convert varchar column to time and use it in a where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to convert a varchar column that has written time information in it. But in an unusual way.

Here a sample of the column dtib

- `Time: 70'000` should be converted to 07:00:00
- `Time: 143'000` should be converted to 14:30:00

I want to make variable on it, so I can use it for example:

```
where btip between &btibA and &btibB
```

and if possible with the column type of `time`.

In the end, I want to create a variable for `btiA = 07:00:00` and 15:00:00 and filter all column that fits in this time range.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why not fix the design and store your time data as a`time`? Querying the data with a conversion is *not* going to be performant. Fixing the design gives you a performant and easy query to write.

Comment: I guess you are going to want to make use of the provided SQL Server string functions to transform it into a format that can convert to a time. Take a look at the docs and have a go.

Comment: im not in the position to make changes on the design. so i need to use it like it is in the moment and make the best its possible on it.

Comment: Frankly, that looks like a bug more than anything else. It's not just "unusual", it's a format no sane person would deliberately choose to store times in, so this is almost certainly a lazy programmer not looking at what their conversions are actually doing. How is `00:00:00` stored?

Comment: It you "can't" fix the design (I doubt this) I would be more tempted to created a "time table" with a row for every value (second) on the day and a `CLUSTERED INDEX` on the `time`, so you could `JOIN` to that table and do a lookup on that. But it wouldnt be as performant as fixing the design still.

Comment: Actually, never mind that. `CONVERT(TIME, STUFF(STUFF(REPLACE(RIGHT('00000' + btip, 7), CHAR(39), ''), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':'))` should do it whether or not the `0` value is padded. Be aware that doing actual comparisons on this value will perform badly and won't be able to make use of an index for range lookups. If you have at least the freedom to add new columns, you could add this as a computed column and index it. If you don't but you are free to create new objects, it would be possible to put this column in a view and index *that* (although this will mean storing data redundantly).

Comment: *" make the best its possible on it."* There isn't one; because of the lack of leading zeroes, the ordering of the values doesn't even respect times. `23:59:59` is **after** `00:00:03` according to your data.

Comment: thanks for the help, i think i will set up the variable as varchar and communicate to filter without dots. just as its on the databes. like this i think i can handle it without any change.

Comment: What should `Time: 1'000` be converted to?

Comment: If you expect to be using this time value as search criteria, I would suggest you consider adding a `PERSISTED` *computed column* of type TIME, and then indexing it. If it is associated with a date from another column, combine the two in a persisted computed DATETIME or DATETIME2 column instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use as below mention code, but I'll suggest to change table design if possible.

```
CONVERT(TIME, STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(REPLACE('00000' + btip, CHAR(39), ''), 6), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':'))
```